# How to add anchor in list element

Tags: python, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I have a list in my rst file that looks like this:

```
- Item 1
- Item 2
- Item 3
```

It renders something like the following (which is exactly what I want):

- Item 1
- Item 2
- Item 3

I would like to create links for each item, so I did

```
.. _item-1:

- Item 1

.. _item-1:

- Item 2

.. _item-1:

- Item 3
```

Now my list renders something like this:

- Item 1
- Item 2
- Item 3

This is clearly happening because of the anchors I inserted between the elements. Is there a way to insert referenc-able anchors inline in sphinx/rST?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is pretty close to the desired result, with funky white space.

```
  .. _item-1:

- Item 1

  .. _item-2:

- Item 2

  .. _item-3:

- Item 3
```

This yields the following output.  Note the `id` attribute is on the parent `<ul>` instead of the first `<li>`, but effectively resolves to the same location on the page.

```
<ul class="simple" id="item-1">
<li>Item 1</li>
<li id="item-2">Item 2</li>
<li id="item-3">Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: That is pretty perfect. I really don't mind the "misplaced" ID for the first item. Any idea why this works?

Comment: White space has meaning in reStructuredText. Indentation of the arbitrary link directive to align with the first character of the list item associates the directive to the context of the list item. More info: http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/user/rst/quickref.html#inline-markup